# Samsung Note 2 onTouchEvent invalid jpeg data, size = 0

Tags: android

I am developing a camera application that capture Images when the user touches the screen
In Samsung galaxy y no problems occurred,but on Note 2 the camera stops and  give me **error in Logcat**  any hint or ideas ??

touch code :

```
@Override 
      public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event ) { // TODO
      //Auto-generated method stub
         Log.d("e", "on touch starts * ");
        System.gc();  
      mCamera.stopPreview();
      Log.d("e", "touch event:   "+event.getActionMasked() );
      switch( event.getAction() ) {
      case 1 :
          Log.d("e", "taken pic action up = 1 * ");
          mCamera.takePicture(shutterCallback, null, mPicture);
          Log.d("e", "taken pic * ");
          Log.d("e", "on touch ends * ");
          return false;
      default:Log.d("e", "default touch event: "+event.getActionMasked() );
  }
    return true;

              }
```

logcat errors

> > 12-03 12:22:06.034: E/SecCameraHardware(1932): **Can't set syscall
> >     setaffinity: result=22=0x16**  12-03 12:22:06.324:E/ISecCameraHardware(1932): android::status_t
> >     android::ISecCameraHardware::**checkArea(ssize_t, ssize_t, ssize_t,
> >     ssize_t, ssize_t, int): All values are zero**  12-03 12:22:06.324:E/ISecCameraHardware(1932): FocusMode=auto,
> >     PrevFocusMode=auto 12-03
> >     12:22:06.359: E/SecCameraHardware(1932): Can't set syscall
> >     setaffinity: result=22=0x16 12-03 12:22:07.479:
> >     E/SecCameraHardware(1932): **getHybridSnapshot**  12-03 12:22:12.834:
> >     E/SecCameraHardware(1932): bool android::SecCameraHardware::**getHybridSnapshot():: invalid jpeg data,
> >     size = 0**
>
> **> pictureThread: error, nativeGetSnapshot** 12-03 12:22:12.834: E/ISecCameraHardware(1932):

Comment: Try to call stopPreview only when event.getAction() === MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN

Comment: it didn't work!  can you please check the logcat messages I have edited it